# JBoss timezone is getting changed automatically

Tags: java, linux, jboss-4.2.x

We are facing one funny and interesting issue with our JBoss app server.

The problem is we are running the JBoss in Linux server which is running in different time zone (say, **America/Chicago**).
Also with the same timezone we are starting the JBoss server by setting **-Duser.timezone=xxx** JVM parameter.
Although it's running fine as per the configuration for 5 or 6 days.
After that the JBoss app server's time zone is getting changed automatically to some other time zone say (**Asia/Kolkata**). For this we have analyzed lot but we are not able to figure it out and as of now restart of JBoss is required to get things normal.

So I wanted to know, is there any way to restrict this or to reset to old timezone without restarting JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the timezone of the server?

You can do it with tzselect command. I had a similar issue recently and I had documented it. You can refer if you want. its [here](http://www.linuxhelp.in/2014/03/changing-timezone-in-linux-systems-using-tzselect.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually here problem is not with our server's timezone. The problem with our JBoss app server only. since JRE's timezone only getting changed and server's timezone remains same.

Comment: Is there anyway to reset the JBoss timezime to other timezone without restarting it ?